# Comparison in UDF in Kusto on tabular data

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to take the table in Kusto and apply a user defined function to individual columns.
In the query below:  I take two columns from a table of type JSON and am comparing them for equality.

```
let MyFilter = (X:(x:dynamic, y:dynamic)) {
    X |  where isnotempty(tostring(x[0].key)) and isnotempty(tostring(y[0].key)) and x[0].key == y[0].key ;
};
tabl
| where MyFilter(ObjJson,ObjJson1) == true
```

However, this code does not seem to work. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

try using the `invoke` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/invokeoperator

```
let MyFilter = (X:(x:dynamic, y:dynamic)) {
    X
    | where isnotempty(tostring(x[0].key)) and 
            isnotempty(tostring(y[0].key)) and 
            tostring(x[0].key) == tostring(y[0].key)
};
table
| invoke MyFilter()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried doing it but because the data is in JSON format. I am getting another error: Cannot compare dynamic values without explicit cast

Comment: did you try replacing `x[0].key == y[0].key` with `tostring(x[0].key) == tostring(y[0].key)`, as shown in the answer? (`tostring()` should be replaced according to the actual datatype you expect to have in your dynamic payload)